# Android 4.2 Does Not Display Toggle Button Correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

I created an app using my Android 2.2 phone. I have four toggle buttons in an activity. I looked at my app on a tablet running Android 4.2 and the light indicator is not on the bottom of the button.

[image: incorrectly displayed toggle]

I first thought that it might be getting cut off so I made the button height `200dp`, but the indicator was still not there.
I was also adjusting the width programmatically, but commenting it out did not help.
The toggle displays correctly on my phone running Android 2.2.

Here is the XML for one of the buttons:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/cat_btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:onClick="toggleClicked"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
```

I decided to create another project with API 17 that had a single toggle button and it displayed correctly so I don't know what is causing the issue in my first project.

Second project image and XML:

[image: correctly displayed toggle]

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="ToggleButton" />
```

Comment: I would get rid of `onClick` on your `ToggleButton` -- please use `setOnCheckedChangedListener()` to respond to changes in the `ToggleButton` state. Also, is your first project using a custom theme that might be interfering with the `ToggleButton` styling?

Comment: I am just using `Theme.Black.NoTitleBar`. Is using a listener recommended on all buttons, or just toggle?

Comment: "Is using a listener recommended on all buttons, or just toggle?" -- `ToggleButton` handles its own click events, as do all subclasses of `CompoundButton`. Hence, use `setOnCheckedChangedListener()`.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. I tried using `Theme` and that did not change the buttons. I also took out `onClick` with still no light indicator.

Comment: You might try poking at both activities in Hierarchy View and see if anything leaps out at you that might be the source of your trouble.

Comment: Something I just noticed in the Graphical Layout. In project 2, when switching API versions from 8 to 17 the toggle button changes to look like the API 8 version when in API 8 and look like API 17 version in API 17. When I switch between those two versions on project 1 it always looks like the API 8 version of a toggle button even when viewing in API 17.

Comment: Well, if you are specifying `Theme.Black.NoTitleBar`, you are not using a `Holo` theme on API 17. If you look at your scrap project, if you created it in Eclipse with a starter activity, you will see a structure for setting up your own custom themes that inherit from different base themes based upon Android API level -- try using that to inherit from `Theme.Holo.NoTitleBar` or something.

Comment: Great, that was it. You can right an official answer if you'd like. I can do it too, just want to give you the credit if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful when using custom themes. In many cases, you need to inherit from a proper parent theme based on the API level to get the look and feel that you want.

A modern project created with an activity from Eclipse will set up style resources for you to encourage this:

- `res/values/styles.xml` defines an `AppBaseTheme`, inheriting from an pre-API Level 11 theme (e.g., `Theme.Light`)
- `res/values-v11/styles.xml` overrides `AppBaseTheme` to inherit from a `Holo` theme (e.g., `Theme.Holo.Light`)
- `res/values-v14/styles.xml` may exist to override `AppBaseTheme` again (e.g., with `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`)
- `res/values/styles.xml` also has `AppTheme`, defined to inherit from `AppBaseTheme`, where you reference `AppTheme` in your manifest and such for your app's theme (or activity's theme)

Put customizations that should work on any API level in `AppTheme`. Put customizations that are API-level-specific in the appropriate `AppBaseTheme`. And, if you want to change the general look (e.g., switch to dark/no-action-bar), change the themes that `AppBaseTheme` inherits from to suit, using ones appropriate for that API level.